# How to List all the Form Fields of Contact Form 7 WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Most of developer while developing a task related to the CF7, they need the type and name of the fields, but generally they failed to grab as the form is stored as a content due to custom post type.

So i can grab all those fields in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of developer while developing a task related to the CF7, they need the type and name of the fields, but generally they failed to grab as the form is stored as a content due to custom post type.

So to fetch type, name, basetype, etc... you need to fetch all contact form post.
You need to loop through every contact form post and pass the content of the form in below scan function as a agument

```
    foreach($form as $objForm){
     $manager = WPCF7_FormTagsManager::get_instance();
     $tags  = $manager->scan( $objForm->form );
     $filter_result = $manager->filter( $tags, $cond );
      foreach ($filter_result as $key => $value) {
          echo $value->type;
          echo $value->name;
      }
   }
```